# How do I use Google's AutoComplete locations API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api

In my HTML I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

and in my Javascript I've added

```js
function initialize() {

var input = document.getElementById('location');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

where location is the ID of my searchbox. When I try to type in a value, there's just a gray exclamation mark at the top and it doesn't allow me to type anything more than one letter.

Comment: is there an error.....?

Comment: No, I'm just getting a gray exclamation mark. Link to my project https://dsopel94.github.io/Eventful/ I'm just starting to learn how to program so perhaps I missed a line of code somewhere. It was actually working initially but 10 minutes later it's suddenly stopped working.

Comment: there is an error for me.... open your browser developer tools and look in the console tab

Comment: "Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following example.

```js
function initialize() {
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });
}

initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet example:

```js
function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('location');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDR924KH0p6IDMCsOaG5rMmEo17JSl5K2U&libraries=places"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script><!-- ← link to javascript file-->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div>Location:</div>
  <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="" autocomplete="off" />

</body>

</html>
```

Note:
It took some time for the API key to be valid but once the API connection works the page will work as well. You might need to refresh the page a few times though as it seems that the API key was having problems connecting at first.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete